# Retrieving relation through another relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following set up in Laravel using Eloquent relations...

```
class AccountNumber extends Model {
    public function account() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that we support multiple types of accounts for which the models have entirely different information.  I'm calling them AccountOfTypeX for the benefit of this example...

```
class AccountOfTypeX extends Model {
    // referenced by AccountNumber
}
```

Next we have some model that is owned by an account; throughout our system, we aways reference AccountNumber as that is the unique identifier of ANY account, no matter what type it is.  So `AccountNumber` and `AccountOfTypeX` basically have an obligatory 1-on-1 relationship.

Any model that is *owned* by an account is linked to an accountnumber which in turn is linked to an account.  We set this up as folloos (in a Trait, but for this example, I'm just providing a dummy class as example):

```
class SomeModel extends Model {
    public function accountnumber() {
        return $this->belongsTo(AccountNumber::class);
    }

    // the below method is added as a convenience to immediately retrieve the account
    public function account() {
        return $this->accountnumber->account();
    }
}
```

This is the behaviour that I'm seeing:

```
$someModel->accountnumber;
// correctly returns the accountnumber model / object

$accountnumber = $someModel->accountnumber;
$accountnumber->account;
// correctly returns the account model / object

$someModel->account();
// correctly returns the MorphTo relationship object

$someModel->accountnumber->account;
// correctly returns the account model / object

$someModel->account;
// **falsely** returns NULL
```

I'm not seeing where I'm doing something wrong here.  I also can't explain why this wouldn't work.  what I do with `$someModel->accountnumber->account` should have the exact same effect of doing `$someModel->account`, should it not?

As a workaround, we have been doing the first, but it doesn't feel right, and I want to be able to use the shortcut helper to immediately get the account without having to write the additional step.

Thanks in advance again for your assistance :-)

Comment: I would try to use [laravel mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: I guess you mean an accessor, and we have thought about it indeed, but shouldn't the above work either?  I'm just trying to understand why it wouldn't.  The reason why we aim for using relations is that we can eagerload, whereas an accessor basically introduces the N+1 problem I believe...

Comment: A while ago I came across a similiar problem with getting relations in model. As far as I know you can't do `$this->accountnumber->account()` because the data for it isn't build at the moment the model loads

Comment: My test cases seem to be confirming that.  Okay - back to accessors then :-)  Such a pity though :-)

Answer (score 0):

$someModel object has not been initialised in the given code.

Comment: Obviously, I just pasted the bits that are important.  You can be sure that $someModel is an instance of SomeModel class, otherwise none of the examples would have returned a result ;-)